# Delete local administrator account with delete() method ADSI with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a powershell script to manage our local administrator accounts using a csv file.

```
#variable to store the data in data.csv
$userobjects = Import-CSV C:-data.csv
function main-list{
   Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
   Write-Host "Windows Powershell Account Manager"
   Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
   Write-Host "1 - Change Name"
   Write-Host "2 - Disabled Account"
   Write-Host "3 - Delete User"
   Write-Host "4 - Exit"



  [int]$action = Read-Host "Enter the menu number from above"
  if ($action -eq 1){change-name}
  if ($action -eq 2){disable-account}
  if ($action -eq 3){delete-user}
  if ($action -eq 4){cls; break}

}



function change-name
{
      foreach ($user in $userobjects)
    {
        #Assign the content to variables
        $FileHostname = $user.Host
        $FileAccount = $user.Account
        $FileNewname = $user.Rename 
        $FileDisable = $user.Disable
        $FileDelete = $user.Delete

            # Rename
            if (($user.Account -ne $user.Rename) -and ($user.Rename -ne '' ))
            {
                #Write-Host "old name :"$FileHostname"/"$FileAccount "-> new name :"$FileHostname"/"$FileNewname
                $connection = $FileHostname+"/"+$FileAccount 
                $accName = [ADSI]("WinNT://$connection")
                if ($accName.path -eq "WinNT://"+$connection+"")
                {
                    $accName.psbase.Rename($FileNewname)
                    Write-Host "Account(s) renamed"
                    $user.Account = $user.Rename
                }
                else
                    {

                        Write-Host "Account name :"$connection "can't be found on the host"
                    }
            $user.Account = $user.Rename
            $userobjects | export-csv C:-data.csv -notype

             }
     }
     Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
     main-list
   }


function disable-account
{
     foreach ($user in $userobjects)
    {
        #Assign the content to variables
        $FileHostname = $user.Host
        $FileAccount = $user.Account
        $FileNewname = $user.Rename 
        $FileDisable = $user.Disable
        $FileDelete = $user.Delete

        if ($user.Disable -eq 'yes')
        {
            $connection = $FileHostname+"/"+$FileAccount 
            $accName = [ADSI]("WinNT://"+$connection+"")

            if ($accName.UserFlags -eq '515')
            {
                Write-Host "Account :"$connection "is already disabled"
            }
            else
            {
                $accName.description = "Account disabled"
                $accName.UserFlags = 2
                $accName.setinfo()
                Write-Host "Account(s) disabled"$connection
            }
        }

    }
    Write-Host "--------------------------------------"
    main-list
}

function delete-user
{
foreach ($user in $userobjects)
    {
        #Assign the content to variables
        $FileHostname = $user.Host
        $FileAccount = $user.Account
        $FileNewname = $user.Rename 
        $FileDisable = $user.Disable
        $FileDelete = $user.Delete


            #Delete
            if ($user.Delete -eq 'yes')
            {
                $connection = $FileHostname+"/"+$FileAccount 
                $accName = [ADSI]("WinNT://"+$connection+"")
                $accName.delete("user",$accName.name)




                   #Write-Host $connection deleted

                }
                else
                    {

                        Write-Host "Account name :"$connection "can't be found on the host"
                    }
            }

    }

}


$userobjects | export-csv C:-\data.csv -notype
main-list
```

I don't really know why I have this message when I am trying to use the delete function : "Unknown name", it is like it doesn't find the local account to delete it but I am not sure. However, It works perfectly when I want to rename or disable accounts.

My data file looks like that 
http://www.noelshack.com/2016-05-1454622367-capture.png
I will post the real message when I will be back to work tomorow.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Quick skim... wouldn't this need to be used instead? I think your `$accName.name` would be using the machine name.

```
 $accName.delete("user",$user.account)
```

Comment: There is the same value in $user.account and $accName.name isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You *`delete()`* the user *from* the computer, so your `[adsi]` object should bind to the computer and call `Delete()` on that instead:

```
# Just the machine name, nothing more:
$Machine = [ADSI]"WinNT://$FileHostname"

# Now delete the user account from the machine
$Machine.Delete('user',$FileAccount)
```